# php artisan serve --host 0.0.0.0 can't be accessed from mobile device on same network

Tags: php, laravel, port, host, laravel-artisan

I have attempted to share my laravel project over a shared network, using;

`php artisan serve --host 192.168.X.XXX --port 8000`

This works and produces no errors but I still can't access my application on other machines connected to the same wifi network, using my Mac's ip address to connect.

I have tried different ports and changed the ip address of my Mac to try and fix it but nothing has worked so far.

Any idea what could be causing this issue?
Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Can you ping your IP?  Likely a firewall issue, either on the router, or on your serving computer.

Comment: If it is a firewall issue I think it would be the router as I haven't changed anything on my mac for a while. I'll try it from home to see if I encounter the same issue from my personal router. As it was working before, I'm just stumped as to why it would suddenly stop.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the command:

`php artisan serve --host=0.0.0.0 --port=8000`

This serves your application over the network, and can be accessed by a url like `http://192.168.0.102`, or whatever is the IPv4 network address of the machine you've served the application on.

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it

Comment: How do you know what IP address i.e. 192.168... was assigned?

Answer (score 1):

Because 0.0.0.0 is another name of 127.0.0.1 and "localhost".
0.0.0.0 means any local (internal) interface. 
You must use IP of your local network (i.e 192.168.x.x)

Comment: I have tried to serve it using my Mac's ip address, for example: 192.132.1.182 but I still can't access it

Comment: Are you shure, that firewall on mac allow incoming connections to laravels port (8000)?

Comment: It used to work before but has recently stopped and unsure how to get it working again. I tried to serve it on different available ports but nothing changed.

Comment: I think I will try to serve my application from my pc at home and from the mac. If it works on both then it's my work's wifi router, if it only works on my pc then the mac is the issue. If it doesn't work on either then I don't know what is wrong with it.

Comment: i think this can be useful for your problem
https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/servers/how-to-access-localhost8000-in-a-remote-server-when-using-php-artisan-serve-digitalocean

Comment: 0.0.0.0 means all IPv4 addresses, not any internal address.

Comment: the network is actually 192.168.*.*** I just put randoms numbers in before. I have edited my question to reflect this.

Comment: Ok, well this answer is wrong.  0.0.0.0 would bind to all addresses, so restricting to 192.168.*.* shouldn't make a difference.